# Given an r time series plot, how can I plot another single point on it?

Tags: r, plot

Data frame:

```
df = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c("2014-01-01","2014-01-02","2014-01-03"),row.names=c('a', 'b', 'c'))

df$b <- as.Date(df$b)
```

and I make a plot:

```
plot(df$b,df$a)
```

How do I add another single point to the plot (coloured red) on a particular day?

I tried:

```
points(as.Date("2014-01-04"),4)
```

But it doesn't show up on the plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your limits are incorrect:

```
plot(df$b,df$a, ylim = c(0,5), xlim = as.numeric(range(df$b))+c(0,1))
points(as.Date("2014-01-04"),4)
```

[image]